# How can I make an Echo (or any Object) invisible?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, invisibility, echo-knight

An Echo knight's echo is an object, which makes it hard to turn invisible, as invisibility and greater invisibility only affect creatures.  What options, from any non-homebrew source, allow you to turn an object (thats not being worn or carried by an invisible creature) invisible in 5e?

Answer (score 1):

[Dust of Disappearance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/dust-of-disappearance) will work.

As an added bonus, it both specifically says that it applies to creatures **and** objects, but the invisibility is only broken prematurely if a **creature** affected by it makes an attack. So your Echo will stay invisible for the entire duration.

A second option is the [Sequester](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Sequester) spell. It's pretty high level, but makes objects invisible. As with the Dust, it only puts *creatures* in statis, so your Echo will be invisible until it's dispelled or it takes damage.

Comment: The echo is an object?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov that's what it says in the OP, I don't know the Echo Knight so I just assumed they were right :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the Echo not only is an object, but also [immune to being invisible](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/188365/if-an-echo-knight-fighter-turns-invisible-do-their-echoes-also-turn-invisible), so this would not work - at least not on an Echo Knight's Echo.